# Load and View data from SFTP using cloudpage

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a way to view data from a file in SFTP in Cloudpage? For eg., when there's an import failure, then an error file gets created and stored in SFTP. As of now, we're importing it into a DE to view the log information. Is there an better way? May be, just give the file name in a cloud page to display the content of the file?